# GCP |Dataproc|How to create a persistent HDFS volumn means even if you delete the dataproc cluster it should not delete the HDFS? Is it possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hdfs, nfs, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

GCP dataproc - HDFS gets deleted automatically when you terminate the dataproc cluster. How to make it persistent HDFS even if you delete the dataproc cluster it should not delete the HDFS? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have specific reason to use HDFS instead of GCS to host your data? The recommendation is to use GCS for job input and output, so that you don't pay for compute when you just need to host the data. If you really need HDFS, you can create a cluster to host HDFS, and create another cluster to point to the remote HDFS with the `core:fs.defaultFS=hdfs://<remote>` property.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage can be used. The connector for this is installed by default in Dataproc. When you shut down a Hadoop cluster, unlike HDFS, you continue to have access to your data in Cloud Storage. [How to use Cloud-Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage)

Comment: when you write data to GCS from spark(in dataproc) , if your data is skewed not properly partitioned. your job gets hanged with one last task for long hours to write in GCS. but when I tried the same job to write in HDFS I did not find this issue. the job ran like a charm. but the only downside is HDFS is temporary, it gets deleted whenever your delete/terminates cluster.

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating a dataproc cluster in GCP , it uses the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) for storage.

According to your Statement when you are terminating a dataproc cluster you HDFS gets automatically deleted , this happens if you are using VM Disks.

HDFS data and intermediate shuffle data is stored on VM boot disks, which are Persistent Disks if  no Local SSD are Provided.

If Local SSD are Attached HDFS will stay in SSD and will not get deleted. VM Boot disks are deleted when the cluster is deleted.

you can check this documentation also to avoid loss of HDFS using VM disk in dataproc.

[Dataproc HDFS](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/dataproc-hdfs)

[Local SSD in Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/dataproc-local-ssds)

Comment: I meant deleting the cluster which is the same as terminating the cluster , so with your statement, if you delete the cluster then VM boot disks will also get deleted then it's the same as VM Disks also gets deleted. how it's going to be persistent. I don't want to pay the bills for the compute engine just to use HDFS. How can we segregate the compute engine with storage . i.e make the storage persistent.

Answer (score 0):

- Looking upon the available documentation it looks like persistent HDFS volumes are not available at this time.
- You can look into the Dataproc [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes) updates to check update about this feature
- Found a similar scenario of your question [What happens to my data when a cluster is shut down](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/resources/faq#what_happens_to_my_data_when_a_cluster_is_shut_down) from the Google official documentation FAQ with a answer which might help you
- As a best practice google is recommending to utilize GCP as persistent storage layer for Dataproc. [Google Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#benefits_of_the_cloud_storage_connector) which will provide you a "Direct data access" to your file stored in Cloud Storage and access them directly.